# "Wear make-up" and "Put on make-up"

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference between **"wear make-up"** and **"put on make-up"**? If yes please give some examples.

Answer (score 9):

A man may say his wife takes forever getting ready before going out, but in nearly every case she'll spend far longer ***wearing makeup*** than she originally spent ***putting on makeup***.

That's to say, ***putting it on*** is the initial process of *applying* makeup - an *activity*, which will be completed after a relatively finite time. After that comes ***wearing it*** - a much more extended "state of being" that has no particular "end, time of completion". If you're drunk or tired enough when you get home after a party, you could go straight to bed and wear makeup all night while you sleep.

Comment: Very much akin to putting on your pants in the morning, and wearing them throughout the day.

Comment: @Doc: Ah, but if I put on my [*gold lame pants*](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=rZweVafLHsXI8QPLloD4AQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=gold+lame+pants+pictures) I could spend the entire evening [*putting on the Ritz*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puttin%27_On_the_Ritz)

Answer (score 8):

I think there is a subtle difference between the two.

*To put on make up* means, *the current activity of putting on/applying make-up*.

*To wear make up* means, *the make-up has already been applied and it is there on your face; you are just bearing with it, rather, carrying it off*.

For example, consider this:

> I am *wearing* make-up.

This sounds more like, "I have applied the make-up long ago. It is still there on my face."

Now consider this:

> I am *putting on* make-up.

This sounds more like, "I am currently applying make-up. I'm doing it right now."

Answer (score 1):

A make-up artist can "put on make-up [on an actor]" and the actor "wears the make-up"